# How to make a character walk(unity 2d)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, game-physics

I'm trying to make my character(a box with 2 long boxes as legs) walk using the legs. The point of the game is the challenge of balancing the character and walking with the legs. I've tried using Hinge Joint 2D but I've never used it before so I have no idea of how to use it. I've also seen people use animations but I'm not sure if it would suit my game well because I want the player to be able to rotate each leg 360 degrees so he could find creative ways of walking. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Joints seem like the best option here. The official unity youtube channel has some good resources for joints: https://www.youtube.com/c/unity/search?query=joint

Answer (score 0):

this is my first answer so please fell free to comment if you have any doubts.

what you and use is making a script to move the leg or in this sense rotate it in one direction. Something like:

```
        GameObject playerLeg;

        Input.GetKeyDown("x");
        playerLeg.transform.Rotate(10, 0, 0);
```

if you don't clamp the Leg rotation you should end up with a 360 rotation.
P.S. don't forget to add colliders to the player Body, legs and Floor.

if you want to go a log way with smoother animation and a bit more complex gameplay further in the game you can check out [Procedural animation](https://youtu.be/e6Gjhr1IP6w)